# Microsoft Teams bot Adaptive Cards Action is received in on_message_activity without data

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

My bot returns an adaptive card in 1:1 private chat with user, the adaptive card configuration is like this,

```
{
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.0",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": f"{jiradetail.summary}",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                    "title": "Comment",
                    "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "version": "1.0",
                        "body": [
                            {
                                "type": "Input.Text",
                                "id": "comment",
                                "isMultiline": True,
                                "placeholder": "Enter your comment"
                            }
                        ],
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "OK",
                                "data": "**jiraid**"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

As you could see, there is a 'comment' textbox and a 'Ok' Action (type Action.Submit, and hidden data->jiraid), the card will be as shown below,

[image]

Now on click on this Ok button, I am receiving the activity in ,

on_message_activity, with the user entered value in the commentbox in the field,

> turn_context.activity.value

but i couldnt get the hidden data which i mapped to the action button, the below picture shows the inspected value of 'turn_context.activity'.

How can i get the mapped data to this action?

[image]

Note:  I was also expecting the callback to be, *on_teams_messaging_extension_submit_action* , but this callback is never called, instead only *on_message_activity* is called.  I assume, its because its an 1:1 conversation and its not invoked via the messageextensions.  Any experts please confirm.

Comment: Please try to pass value in Adaptive card data "data": {"value": "yourCommentValue"}

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "on_teams_messaging_extension_submit_action" - it's not because it's a 1-1, rather it's because it is NOT a "message extension", it's just a regular Adaptive Card action.

With regards the main issue, about the data not appearing, try to avoid having a direct string value as the "data" payload, and instead try with an object, like this:

`...
"data": {"value": "**jiraid**"}
...`

Comment: As per the adaptive cards syntax, data can be a direct string, and i understand why you are saying this,  because in a normal hero card, the value field should be a json object, cant be a direct string.  Here i tried both.

Comment: Per the -syntax-, yes, but per -guidance-, strings are best to be avoided.

Comment: yeah. I understand.  But i followed it.. but still didnt work

Comment: @ThiyagaB - No one ever said that you can use string submit actions with input fields. You can't. And if you actually did try this solution and it's still not working, please update your question so that we can see your attempt to do things the correct way. We cannot comment on what you might be doing wrong if we don't see it. (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @kyleDelaney I found the answer and posted here for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-actions#

For easy reference, this what we are supposed to do,

> Adaptive Cards support three action types:
>
> - Action.OpenUrl
> - Action.Submit
> - Action.ShowCard
>
> In addition to the
> actions mentioned above, you can modify the Adaptive Card
> Action.Submit payload to support existing Bot Framework actions using
> a msteams property in the data object of Action.Submit. The below
> sections detail how to use existing Bot Framework actions with
> Adaptive Cards.

So the updated payload will be,  refer the payload 'msteams' under action->data,

```
{
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "version": "1.0",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "Container",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": f"{jiradetail.summary}",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.ShowCard",
                    "title": "Comment",
                    "card": {
                        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                        "version": "1.0",
                        "body": [
                            {
                                "type": "Input.Text",
                                "id": "comment",
                                "isMultiline": True,
                                "placeholder": "Enter your comment"
                            }
                        ],
                        "actions": [
                            {
                                "type": "Action.Submit",
                                "title": "OK",
                                "data": {
                                "msteams": {
                                    "type": "invoke",
                                    "value": {"jiraid":f"{jiradetail.issueid}"}
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```